# Having trouble updating and deleting data in SwiftUI from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Currently in my SwiftUI reading and adding data from Firebase Firestore works fine. Issues arise when a user tries to edit or delete data. When editing, instead of just updating the values of the current data set, a duplicate version of the data is made with the changes. When a user tries to delete data, nothing happens.

Made a new github repo for help: https://github.com/ronjj/FirebaseTest/tree/master/FirebaseTest/ProjectsPages

Project Model

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct Project: Identifiable, Codable{
@DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString

var title: String
/* I used Google Auth in my full app*/
   // var creator: String = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "N/A"
var color: Color
var assignedStudents: [String]
var notes: String


enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case title
    //case creator
    case color
    case assignedStudents
    case notes
 }
}
```

Project List View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProjectsListView: View {
// MARK: - State
@StateObject var viewModel = ProjectsViewModel()
@ObservedObject var viewModel2 = ProjectViewModel()
@State var presentAddProjectSheet = false


// MARK: - UI Components
private var addButton: some View {
    Button(action: { self.presentAddProjectSheet.toggle() }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }
}

private func projectRowView(project: Project) -> some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: ProjectDetailsView(project: project )) {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(project.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Project Creator Name")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                .foregroundColor(project.color)
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach (viewModel.projects) { project in
                projectRowView(project: project)
            }
            .onDelete() { indexSet in
                viewModel.removeProjects(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Projects")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
        .onAppear() {
            print("ProjectsListView appears. Subscribing to data updates.")
            self.viewModel.subscribe()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$presentAddProjectSheet) {
            ProjectEditView()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Project View Model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

class ProjectViewModel: ObservableObject {
// MARK: - Public properties
@Published var project: Project
@Published var modified = false

// MARK: - Internal properties
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

// MARK: - Constructors

init(project: Project = Project(title: "", color: Color.blue,assignedStudents: [], notes: "...")) {
    self.project = project
    
    self.$project
        .dropFirst()
        .sink { [weak self] project in
            self?.modified = true
        }
        .store(in: &self.cancellables)
}

// MARK: - Firestore

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

private func addProject(_ project: Project) {
    do {
        let _ = try db.collection("projects").addDocument(from: project)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

private func updateProject(_ project: Project) {
    if let documentId = project.id {
        do {
            try db.collection("projects").document(documentId).setData(from: project)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

private func updateOrAddProject() {
    if let _ = project.id {
        self.updateProject(self.project)
    }
    else {
        addProject(project)
    }
}

private func removeProject() {
    if let documentId = project.id {
        db.collection("projects").document(documentId).delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UI handlers

func handleDoneTapped() {
    self.updateOrAddProject()
}

func handleDeleteTapped() {
    self.removeProject()
}

}
```

Projects View Model

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore

class ProjectsViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var projects = [Project]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()
private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

deinit {
    unsubscribe()
}

func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
        listenerRegistration?.remove()
        listenerRegistration = nil
    }
}

func subscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
        listenerRegistration = db.collection("projects").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.projects = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Project.self)
            }
        }
    }
}

func removeProjects(atOffsets indexSet: IndexSet) {
    let projects = indexSet.lazy.map { self.projects[$0] }
    projects.forEach { project in
        if let documentId = project.id {
            db.collection("projects").document(documentId).delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Unable to remove document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: While adding a link to your github is fine, if that link breaks to changes, it would totally invalidate the question for future readers. It's best practice to include code in your question. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, while there is code in the question, it not complete enough to understand the issue. For example; the code references `project.id` but we have no idea where that comes from or how it's populated - if we take the code as is, that's always nil which is why nothing deletes.

Comment: @Jay. Should I edit this post with the changes you suggested or make a new post?

Comment: Edit please and we will take a look. Remember we need a *minimal* example - don't overwhelm us with code.

Comment: @Jay I added some code here for you to look at. All of the code is in the new github repo I made. Didn't want to put too much code here. https://github.com/ronjj/FirebaseTest/tree/master/FirebaseTest/ProjectsPages

Comment: The amount of code in the question is not minimal and it's unlikely anyone here will go to github and review the entire project in an attempt to troubleshoot; it's too much data. You can help us to help you by updating the question with minimal code and show your troubleshooting steps. More importantly, review my comment above **the code references project.id but we have no idea where that comes from**. Even with updated code we still don't know. If it's nil, then the behavior you're seeing is correct. Have you stepped through your code? If so, at what line do things not work correctly?

Comment: Also, this `var creator: String = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "N/A"` is not a good idea as if Authentication fails you won't be able to read any data. The code should stop at that point and handle the error.

Comment: @Jay I found the issue. it was in my project model. in my enum for CodingKeys, I didn't have a case for id. Once I added the id case and modified id to be DocumentID var id: String? , deleting and modifying started to work. In regards to your comment about the variable creator not working if authentication fails, in the actual app, the user would not even get to the project screen if not authenticated so I think it's fine.